# Dont receive any information from docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm struggling to move my web api to the docker containers. However, it doesnt want to run.
Running `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up` console shows me that app is start listening on: http://localhost:5000 and https://localhost:5001, but before those line i'm receiving: " Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'."

Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

```
COPY ["ShoppingCart.API/ShoppingCart.API.csproj", "ShoppingCart.API/"]
#COPY ["ShoppingCart.Domain.Entities/ShoppingCart.Domain.Entities.csproj", "ShoppingCart.Domain.Entities/"]
#COPY ["ShoppingCart.Domain.Interfaces/ShoppingCart.Domain.Interfaces.csproj", "ShoppingCart.Domain.Interfaces/"]
#COPY ["ShoppingCart.Infrastructure.Data/ShoppingCart.Infrastructure.Data.csproj", "ShoppingCart.Infrastructure.Data/"]
#COPY ["ShoppingCart.Infrastructure.Business/ShoppingCart.Infrastructure.Business.csproj", "ShoppingCart.Infrastructure.Businesss/"]
#COPY ["ShoppingCart.Services.Interfaces/ShoppingCart.Services.Interfaces.csproj", "ShoppingCart.Services.Interfaces/"]

RUN dotnet restore "ShoppingCart.API/ShoppingCart.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ShoppingCart.API"
RUN dotnet build "ShoppingCart.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ShoppingCart.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/build .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ShoppingCart.API.dll"]
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.9'

networks:
 localdev:
  name: localdev

services:
 main-api:
  build: .
  restart: always
  ports:
   - "5000:80"
   - "5001:443"
  networks:
   - localdev
```

So, on http://localhost:5000 and https://localhost:5001 i dont see anything...
I even tried to add some arguments to Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ShoppingCart.API.dll", "--urls", "https://0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

And after this, i dont receive the error of not assignning requested address. And also, cant reach any content on those ports...

Comment: It looks like you need to use {DOCKER_IP} instead of "localhost" if I want to have communication between two API in two different containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

You are binding port `5000` **on your localhost** to `80` **on your docker container** (and same with 5001:443).  Is that really what you want to do?  Since this is an aspnet-core project you are most likely running your webapp on port 5000 or 5001 (in the container), not 80 or 443.  It also seems that you may already be running something on port 5000 on your localhost so docker is failing to bind it (I assume you're running your app probably).

### Solution

You most likely need to:

1. Bind to ports 5000/5001 in your container, not 80/443.
2. Shut down what's running on port 5000 in your localhost environment, or pick another port to bind that isn't in use.

For example, lets pick a random higher port that isn't being used:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
 main-api:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "6000:5000"
   - "6001:5001"
```

Bring this up with `docker-compose up` and then see what you get from `http://localhost:6000` or `https://localhost:6001`.

### Notes

- It looks like you're attempting to create a multi-stage docker build where your app is built inside the `sdk` image and then run inside the `aspnet` image.  But you are not introducing the `aspnet` image, so your container's runtime environment is still `sdk` which includes a lot of stuff we don't need in the runtime.  You should add this line after your publish to change to the `aspnet` image.  [Example](https://docs.docker.com/samples/dotnetcore/).

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
```